# Remove extra space in datagridview cell in c# windows applilcation

Tags: c#, datagridview, space

I have a datagridview. It contains four columns. qr Code and QR Code are columns of type DataGridViewImageColumn.

[image]

I need to remove the space shown by red rectangular box. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the `Height` of your Rows `dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Height` is set to something small.  Also check your `Width` on your Columns `dataGridView1.Columns["QR Code"].Width`.  Then you may want to try something like this:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
dataGridView1.Columns["qr Code"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
dataGridView1.Columns["QR Code"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Comment: I have not set any cell height. From the Properties window, minimumWidth and width is set 5 for image column. And gridview data is bind by the following syntax:                                                                                                            dgvPrint.DataSource = qrInfos;

Comment: If it is not working then my guess is that the image itself is the one that has  the margins.  I did test this code and I do not see any margin on my side.